# Move iptables rule (w/o removing and adding)

Tags: iptables

Is there a way to move a rule in the `iptables` and change it position ? I'm aware i can use `-I` to insert a rule in a specific position, but i also like to keep the counters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you cannot move a rule.  However, you can set the counter for any rule you add/insert/replace (using the `-c` or `--set-counters` parameter).  So you could check the current count, delete the rule and reinsert it with the old count value.

Answer (score 44):

You can also do following

1. Write the output of `iptables-save` to a file:
   `iptables-save > /tmp/iptables.txt`
2. Edit this file with a text editor, move whichever line you want.
3. Reload the file: `iptables-restore < /tmp/iptables.txt`

Comment: *slaps forehead*

Answer (score 6):

To see what you have and what you want to change you first need to do some examination.

1. Check for counters and write these somewhere so you can enter them later.

   ```
   iptables-save -c
   ```
2. Check for the line you want to replace / reposition using

   ```
   iptables -L -v -n --line-n
   ```
3. Write the rule in the designated CHAIN and add the counters explained in step on. For example.

   ```
   iptables -R INPUT 5 -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp -c 3441 472271 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Some comment"
   ```

Meaning of `-c`

`-c [packets:bytes]`

The above iptables rule will be entered on line 5.

You can save the current iptables (and counters) by doing

```
iptables-save -c -f /somepath/iptrules-$(date +%F)
```

Comment: use ip6tables instead if you're (also) dealing with ipv6

Answer (score 1):

Display iptables lines number:

```
iptables -L --line-numbers -n

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     all  --  192.6.3.2            anywhere            
2    ACCEPT     all  --  192.6.3.1            anywhere            
3    ACCEPT     all  --  192.6.3.0            anywhere
```

Let's say that you want to move the **rule Nb 3 to the rule Nb 2** do this:

```
iptables -I INPUT 2 -s 192.6.3.0 -j ACCEPT
```

**-I**: to insert

**INPUT**: Name of the chain

**2**: Position **number** where you want to insert the chain

**-s 192.6.3.0 -j ACCEPT**: rule to insert at the position number

Delete your old rule Nb 3 which is now in position Nb 4:

```
iptables -D INPUT 4
```

As we insert a new rule, the old rule that was in the third position is now in the fourth position.

Comment: I get "Bad argument `3'" with this example

Comment: My bad I get it wrong, I fix my post

Comment: I was aware of this method, but the key part was to keep the rule counter, and this is where the `-c` option come. So in the end I was not able to move a rule, but to reinsert it in the new position, and remove the old rule. (which mimic a rule move)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the [answer from Valentin Bajrami](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146364/100397):

if you have your current iptables rules and counters to a file using

`iptables-save -c -f /somepath/iptrules-$(date +%F)`

you can then modify the file with your required changes

`nano /somepath/iptrules-$(date +%F)`

then restore with counters by doing

`iptables-restore -c /somepath/iptrules-$(date +%F)`

Both commands above could be replaced with ip6tables if you're dealing with ipv6